# How to open project.json in .NET Core 2

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have VS 2017 with .NET Core 2 project. How can I open project.json? It is not listed in Solution Explorer. I can find appsettings.json, but not project.json. Should I open it by right clicking project and choosing some settings?

Comment: `project.json` files, while having a lot of popular support, [ended up being rather short lived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`project.json` files are no longer supported. Instead, .NET Core apps now use `csproj` files.

Right click your project and select "Edit ProjectName.csproj" to view the file.

Answer (score 0):

project.json doesn't have support from .net core 2.0 .

you can get the mapping of the project.json to csproj from link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj